# como puedo tener "un orden a seguir" en mis esquemas de mongoDB?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

soy nuevo en mongoDB y me gusta la idea de que mongo no es tan estricto como una base de datos relacional, pero al momento de definir la estructura de mis documentos json me surgen dudas.

**mi pregunta es,** hay alguna manera de poner un poco de “orden” al momento de definir cual será nuestra estructura(esquema) de los documentos??, tal vez con un example.json en el cual definimos como son las estructuras de los documentos, o un readme.txt??, para de esa manera dejarle claro a otros desarrolladores como esta definida la estructura.

todo esto lo pregunto porque estaba viendo un tutorial en youtube en donde en vez de usar el **modulo nativo de mongodb** para nodejs usaban una librería llamada **mongoose** , y había una parte en la cual se definía el esquema con mongoose donde incluso se ponía que tipo de dato se esperaba, esto no lo he visto aún en el modulo nativo de mongodb para nodejs.

y la duda me surge debido a que , **¿ no se supone que mongodb es una base de datos sin esquemas ?**, en la cual los documentos lo podemos ir guardando con la estructura que queramos no importa si la cambiamos, asi que, para retomar mi pregunta… , cual sería la mejor manera de mantener o por lo menos tratar de mantener un esquema para cierto tipo de documentos json ? , de tal manera que yo en un futuro u otros desarrolladores puedan ver facilmente como estan estructurados los documentos.

espero alguien me saque de dudas jeje, saludos y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

`MongoDB` trabaja con `colecciones`, con `mongoDB` no es como las BD relacionales, al ser una base de datos `no - relacional` no trabaja con tablas, si no con las colecciones comentadas anteriormente.
Como comentas guarda los datos en una estructura similar a un `json`, que se llama `BSON`.
En este enlace te explica bien en que se basa [Bases de MongoDB](https://www.adolfocuadros.com/bases-de-datos/aprendiendo-mongodb/)

Y aquí te dejo otro de paso a paso como trabaja este esquema para empezar a tratar los datos [MongoDB insertado de datos](https://www.genbeta.com/desarrollo/mongodb-empezando-por-el-principio-insertando-datos).

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo